# Propagation speed of air humidity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, air, diffusion, convection, humidity

I'm currently playing with relative air humidity and temperature sensor that makes measurements in my living room once every 60s. When plotted the data on a chart I noticed that spikes and dips of humidity very closely correlate with events in the room: i can clearly see a spike when I wake up in the morning and do myself a cup of tea or take shower. Similarly, the chart line plummets when i leave the house. On the other hand temp data doesn't seem to show any response to the events in the room.

The question is: how the speed of moisture traveling in air is defined?
When a kettle in one corner of a room starts to boil, how soon will this be detected by a sensor in the opposite corner?

Answer (score 2):

if there is fan-forced heating in your room or convection moving the air around, the time constant for sharing humidity is on the order of minutes. if diffusion (no bulk air movement) is the only mechanism available, the answer is on the order of hours.

Answer (score 0):

In a closed window envirinment in a room the fastest way of moving air is convection.

And convection depends on the geometry of the room, the walls, and even furniture. The trace of dust over walls and furniture in rooms not dusted for a while will be kind of an indicator of the flow of air.

If there is draft in the room especially from lower to higher part the flow of convection will be faster.

Depending on the gradient of humidity and temeratur in the absence of ventilation the air will stratify and stagnate in a few hours.

An explanation for your sensor not being sensitive to local fast chenges in temps could be the way it is set up. If it reads infrared readiation, it is possible it'looks' at some distance.

Answer (score 0):

As someone alluded to, the response rate to temperature depends on the temperature sensor - but even if it's dissimilar metals, the size of the contact point and the amount of solder at the contact point between the metals makes a big difference in how fast it will respond.  A "cheaper" sensor will respond very slowly because it's likely to be much bigger.  I worked in a lab where we cared about such things.

Answer (score 0):

By numbers, the $H_2O$-gas -air diffusion constant at normal $T,p$ conditons is $25*10^{-6}\ \frac{ m^2}{s}$

It follows, that in a atmosphere at abolute rest, after $10^6 s$,  an amount of water molecules starting in the origin is distributed as a Gaussian over a ball with about $25 m^2$ of surface area, mod factors of $\sqrt \pi$. In a box its nearly equally distributed after a day$.

Just experienced while drying the floor of a cellar room with an humidity absorber. Needs about 3 weeks. Same effect by low humidity air flow  through open windows on a sunny period for 2 days.